# How do I add some inserts in rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

After creating a table (by migration), I want to insert some entries directly. How must I write a migration for this?

thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:**
This is the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2667747/7852

---

Here's an example from [ruby on rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html):

```
 class AddSystemSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
    # create the table
    def self.up
      create_table :system_settings do |t|
        t.string  :name
        t.string  :label
        t.text  :value
        t.string  :type
        t.integer  :position
      end

      # populate the table
      SystemSetting.create :name => "notice", :label => "Use notice?", :value => 1
    end

    def self.down
      drop_table :system_settings
    end
  end
```

Comment: Using a model is bad practice since models change over time, per the response below - use SQL

Comment: As mentioned by others, that is not the right approach. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2667747/7852

Comment: bad practice, don't use models in migrations

Answer (score 101):

**Don't**.  If you're looking for seed data, you should use `db/seeds.rb` and `rake db:seed` instead.  [More info in this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data).

Side note: Always make sure that the code in `db/seeds.rb` is idempotent. i.e. It should always be safe to re-run your seeds.

But, if you must insert or modify data inside a migration (there are legitimate use-cases for this), it's best to use SQL statements instead.  Your model class isn't guaranteed to still be around in the same form in a future version of your application, and running the migrations from scratch in the future might yield errors if you reference the model class directly.

```
execute "insert into system_settings (name, label, value) values ('notice', 'Use notice?', 1)"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was writing.  The written out version of the Railscast is here:  http://asciicasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Comment: You are so unbelievably right it is ridiculous. I just completely screwed up big time thinking it was fine to write migrations that seed your tables. Terrible. Terrible. Terrible. If you don't trust this answer, trust me when I say "your Models WILL and DO change as time progresses as you update your code". When this DOES occur, your seeding migrations are botched and you LOSE DATA....(luckily I back things up). Now I just have to figure out how to put my data back in automagically after-the-fact.

Comment: There are advantages to locating your data with the migration that creates its table. Maybe the table is meaningless when empty. Maybe you want to extend rails' db versioning to data. Maybe you think using only one file for all seed/configuration data is loco (it is!). You don't need to be dogmatic about saying "NEVER" add data in migrations, if your only reason is that doing it via models is bad. I only say this because this is a high-volume question, and knowing how to do it well is what the poster asked.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind this but it seems to me like there may be legitimate reasons to add/update data. For instance, I have a migration that creates a new model relates it to an pre-existing model. I want to insert a new instance of the new model for every instance of that existing model. Wouldn't it make sense to create the table and insert the initial data for that table in the same place? I'm not seeding the whole database, just this one table.

Comment: How do you do SQL escaping in this approach?

Comment: But you can't either guarantee that in future your table schema would be same or around. So how would writing sql statements would be better?

Comment: @AliArslan You clearly aren't understanding the underlying notion of migrations. If you're running through the migrations, of course the schema is going to match the expected schema at the time the migration is being run; otherwise, the migration wouldn't need to run.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for the explanation. I completely understand your point now.

Comment: -1 For lack of a detailed explanation, with example(s), of why adding data through migration files is not a good idea. The Railscast video you link to, also lacks this. It only touches on the topic with this one line: "I'm not really a fan of this approach. I prefer to keep migrations just focused on altering the database schema." Sounds subjective. The other link appears dead. You also mention that it's best to use SQL statements instead. Again, why? I'll remove the downvote once you've added better explanation. Examples examples examples.

Comment: I find this answer very subjective. It doesn't help that the Rails guide itself provides an API reference for doing so and presents no negative opinion on doing it: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data. Granted the answer is from 2010 and so the perspective on this might have changed.

Comment: how is adding something to the "seeds" file going to work when you are adding new tables to an existing database that is already seeded? you don't want to re-run seeds.

Comment: @MattMcKnight Yes, you do want to re-run seeds. Seeds should be written in a way that is idempotent. It should always be safe to re-run seeds, because it should only create records that don't already exists. This is often accomplished with a `thing = Thing.find_or_initialize_by(...)` followed by a subsequent `thing.update(...)`.

Comment: I still don't understand why having data in the migration is such a bad thing....??

Comment: Reason for not adding data in migrations: if your data model changes (e.g. you add a mandatory field) your migrations will break. You will either have to edit old migrations (Rails advises against this) or use e.g. `db:schema:load` instead which means you won't have the data you added in the migrations if you re-set the DB. @Ryan McGeary could you add some practical example to your answer?

Comment: Migrations should never rely on application code anyway, so if they're seeding data they should define their own Active Record classes to do so. It's not ALWAYS bad practice, and there ARE valid use cases for loading data in migrations rather than a seeds file, so these dogmatic answers simply aren't helpful.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit: PLEASE NOTE - Posters above are correct, you should not populate the DB inside migrations.  Don't use this to add new data, only to modify data as part of changing the schema.**

For many things, using raw SQL will be preferable, but if you need to insert data as part of a migration (for instance, doing data conversion when breaking out a table into multiple tables), and you want some default AR stuff like convenient DB-independent escaping, you can define a local version of the model class:

```
class MyMigrationSucksALittle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    # empty guard class, guaranteed to have basic AR behavior
  end

  ### My Migration Stuff Here
  ### ...

end
```

Note that this works best for simple cases; since the new class is in a different namespace (`MyMigrationSucksALittle::MyModel`), polymorphic associations declared in the guard model won't work correctly.

A somewhat more detailed overview of available options is located here: http://railsguides.net/2014/01/30/change-data-in-migrations-like-a-boss/

Comment: The link provided is now broken

Answer (score 4):

create a new migration file like
047_add_rows_in_system_settings.rb

```
 class AddRowsInAddSystemSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
        def self.up
          SystemSetting.create{:name => "name1", :label => "Use notice?", :value => 1}
          SystemSetting.create{:name => "name2", :label => "Use notice?", :value => 2}
         end

        def self.down
          SystemSetting.delete_all
        end
      end
```

OR

while creating table

046_system_settings.rb

```
class AddSystemSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      create_table :system_settings do |t|
        t.string  :name
        t.string  :label
        t.text  :value
        t.string  :type
        t.integer  :position
      end

      SystemSetting.create :name => "notice", :label => "Use notice?", :value => 1
    end

    def self.down
      drop_table :system_settings
    end
  end
```

Ref:- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: I like this approach but am wondering if this is really a best practice?  The user above suggests that it is not.

Comment: I won't down vote but it IS bad practice, as you stated, @Tronathan. Read my comment above and don't make the same mistake I did.

Answer (score 0):

There are references to using Models in Migrations from trusted sources: [The main purpose of Rails' migration feature is to issue commands that modify the schema using a consistent process. Migrations can also be used to add or modify data. This is useful in an existing database that can't be destroyed and recreated, such as a production database.](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)

Seeding should be `idempotent` as stated in the accepted answer. Meaning that they should be safe to run in Production even if only by accident. Therefore the [`find_or_create_by`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) method can and should be used in these cases.

We can then leverage the Models in our migrations as follows:

```rb
class CreateMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    create_table :my_model do |t|
      # table code here
    end

    MyModel.find_or_create_by(**my_model_attributes)
  end

  def down
    drop_table :my_model
  end
end
```

***As with anything we are doing, especially in production, we should do it with understanding, caution and intent.***

An advanced use of this approach can be used to adjust a production DB schema and models to reflect and build new references to newer models over time.  This can be done in a single migration using this approach, especially when paired with:

- [add_reference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)
- [reset_column_information](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_column_information)