# rails generate migration command to insert data into the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table and I had to add a migration script to add rows in the table.
Please help with the rails generate migration command to insert data into the table.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: You might also like to look at the seed rake task, e.g. http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add some inserts in rails migration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667580/how-do-i-add-some-inserts-in-rails-migration)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can write regular ruby code inside a migration. So you can simply do something like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    User.create(:username => "Hello", :role => "Admin")
  end
  def self.down
    User.delete_all(:username => "Hello")
  end
end
```

Just write regular ruby inside your migration same as you would in pry or rails console.

Comment: Agreed, using raw sql inserts is better since it won't trigger validations that came to the code at a later stage.

Comment: Use `create` instead of `new`. `new` just create a instance, `create` makes a new instance and save it into table

Answer (score 4):

The code helped me is the sql statement as show

In migration file

```
def up
execute("insert into salary_ranges(salary_range) values('Above 2000');")
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class AddFieldInUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :null => false, :default => 0
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users
  end
end
```

Comment: Please don't add code only answers. Can you leave some description for your code that describes how it addresses the problem?

Comment: than use below migration script:
ruby db:migrate