# SQL code tests to verify migration was successful

Tags: sql, teradata

I had a question regarding testing data after migration.

I have used the basic testing queries to verity the data has been migrated successfully but now I cannot think of anymore.  Any additional advise would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the ones I have used so far:

-Record Count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

-Sum columns

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

-Check for Null

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name
      WHERE column_name IS NULL
```

I am checking the output results are the same in the source system and the target system.  To clarify, the old source systems are a mixture of different databases. SQL server 2005,2008 and Sybase. The target side is Teradata. all the data has moved over to Teradata.

Comment: When you say "migrated", do you mean you have test or sample data in your migration files? If so, generally not a good idea. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2667747/877472) out and the posted RailsCast episodes for some info on that. Other than that, I believe this question might be too localized, as we have no idea what kind of data you have, or what sorts of things you want to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing the two tables to make sure they are the same? I'm assuming when you say "source system" and "target system" you have two tables.  Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.column_name = t1.column_name)
```

Or find records which exist in source table but not in target table, as well as records which exists in target table but not in source table:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id, column_name FROM t1, 'old'
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, column_name FROM t2, 'new') t
ORDER BY Id
```

The code will vary based on what RDBMS you're using, but the ideas should be the same.

Comment: To clarify, the old source systems are a mixture of different databases. SQL server 2005,2008 and Sybase. The target side is Teradata.  all the data has moved over to Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of different things you can do, depending on how certain you want to be that your data matches "exactly". It also depends on how certain systems treat NULL - in oracle, for example, a null string is the empty string, whereas in SQL server, '' and NULL are not equivalent.

If your DBMSs are the same on both the source and target, you can use tricks such as (in SQL Server) `SUM(CHECKSUM(concatenation_of_my_fields))` to get a sense if you really have the same data.

There's a lot of assumptions you have to make, though. You really have to identify the best test cases for your migration scenario yourself. You've listed most of the general ones that are typically done already.

However, migrations aren't always just "copy table a to table b". For more advanced cases, you need to work with your business team and identify all the true test cases.

Comment: To clarify, the old source systems are a mixture of different databases. SQL server 2005,2008 and Sybase. The target side is Teradata.  all the data has moved over to Teradata.