# What is the best way to convert a has_many relation to has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have a has_many relation in my app. e.g. department has many users.
I want to covert it to a has_and_belongs_to_many relation.
As part of the migration I need to preserve the current relation between users and departments, meaning I have to move all the data to the new connecting table.
This is the migration I created:

```
class CreateUserDepartment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users_departments do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :department
    end

    ###############################################
    # need to move the data to the new table here #
    ###############################################

    remove_column :users, :sub_department_id
  end

end
```

what is the best way to write the missing line?

Answer (score 1):

If you must, you can use `execute "your SQL"`. See this question:

[How do I add some inserts in rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667580/how-do-i-add-some-inserts-in-rails-migration/2667747#2667747)

The main value of the "Don't" answer to that question is in explaining why you would not want to use your models to do this. Also, I'd be surprised if you can or would want to do this using `change`, you would probably need to use `self.up`.