# how to create migration on rails with raw sql (postgres) with large data set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, rails-migrations

I wanted to insert data into a related table. A 1 to many relationships. After searching the best practice I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667580/how-do-i-add-some-inserts-in-rails-migration/2667747) and then I implemented this.

```
class InsertDataIntoPermissionAndPermissionGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    execute <<-SQL
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WITH a AS (
      INSERT INTO spree_permission_groups (name, created_at, updated_at)
      VALUES ('role_manager', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING id
      ) 
    INSERT INTO 
      spree_permissions (name, action, permission_group_id, created_at, updated_at)
      SELECT 'Role', 'manage', id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM a
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WITH b AS (
      INSERT INTO spree_permission_groups (name, created_at, updated_at)
      VALUES ('department_manager', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING id
      ) 
    INSERT INTO 
      spree_permissions (name, action, permission_group_id, created_at, updated_at)
      SELECT 'Department', 'manage', id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM b
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WITH c AS (
      INSERT INTO spree_permission_groups (name, created_at, updated_at)
      VALUES ('holiday_manager', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) RETURNING id
      ) 
    INSERT INTO 
      spree_permissions (name, action, permission_group_id, created_at, updated_at)
      SELECT 'Holiday', 'manage', id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM c
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SQL
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

but I have more than 300 data. Is this still the right way of doing this? or I can import an excel data and do rails `create` method.

I also have an Error. Thought this will ok since I wrap it in sql.

```
Caused by:
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 14:     WITH b AS (
             ^
```

**UPDATE**

fixed error

Comment: Why do you insert them in the migration?, You could have inserted the records in the rake task right?

Comment: @Aarthi we don't have really because this will be just done once. is this wrong?

Comment: Please checkout this https://thoughtbot.com/blog/data-migrations-in-rails.

Comment: @Aarthi thanks for this. This is a great blog. I'll discuss this with my senior. He's the one who recommends the migration.

Comment: Sure, That depends on the use case. There is another option to populate the data. check out this http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do insert records in rake task. And you can use Active record import gem(https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to insert bulk data to the table. **You can even use active record import in migration too**. Do check the gem documentation for using more available options.

For creating rake tasks, you can refer this - https://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/

```
        desc 'task description'
        task :bulk_insert_records => :environment do |_, args|

          spree_permission_groups = ['holiday_manager', 'department_manager', 'role_manager']

          spree_permission_groups_list = []

          spree_permission_groups.each do |spree_permission_group|
            spree_permission_groups_list << SpreePermissionGroup.new(name: spree_permission_group)
          end

          SpreePermissionGroup.import(spree_permission_groups_list)


         # Likewise use the id of the created records to set permissions
        end
```