# Rails: How to modify data using migrations due to change in the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-migrations, apartment-gem

I have following two migrations:

One, Add column `contextual_page_number` to `transcripts` table:

```
class AddContextualPageNumberToTranscripts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :transcripts, :contextual_page_number, :integer, default: 1
  end
end
```

Second, changing the value of the previous added column `contextual_page_number` based on value of another column:

```
class ChangePageOffsetAndContextualPageNumberOfTranscripts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    Firm.all.find_in_batches do |group|
      group.each do |firm|
        Apartment::Tenant.switch(firm.tenant) do
          Transcript.where.not(page_offset: 0).each do |transcript|
            transcript.update(
              contextual_page_number: ((transcript.page_offset - 1) * -1),
              page_offset: 1
            )
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    ..
  end
end
```

After running the migration, I am getting unknown attribute `contextual_page_number` error.

> == 20211108132509 AddContextualPageNumberToTranscripts: migrating =============
> -- add_column(:transcripts, :contextual_page_number, :integer, {:default=>1})    -> 0.0095s
> == 20211108132509 AddContextualPageNumberToTranscripts: migrated (0.0096s) ====
>
> == 20220113095658 ChangePageOffsetAndContextualPageNumberOfTranscripts: migrating  rails
> aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later
> migrations canceled:
>
> unknown attribute 'contextual_page_number' for Transcript.

I have even tried `reset_column_information`, but no luck:

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch(firm.tenant) do
  Transcript.connection.schema_cache.clear!
  Transcript.reset_column_information
  ..
end
```

Any clue would be of great help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add some inserts in rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667580/how-do-i-add-some-inserts-in-rails-migration)

Comment: Does schema.rb include contextual_page_number after you run the migrations? Also, can you access the contextual_page_number attribute in the console?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in one of the answer, I tried `reset_column_information` just right after the `add_column`, but that didn't worked. Finally, SQL to the rescue..

```
sql_cmd = "UPDATE transcripts
           SET contextual_page_number = ((page_offset - 1) * -1),
               page_offset = 1
           WHERE page_offset != 0"

Transcript.connection.execute(sql_cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two migration files.
First, try running the migration and check `schema.rb` for the table `transcripts` and verify that the newly added column `contextual_page_number` is being added or not.

Once you are sure that your new column is added, then again create a new migration like, eg: *`MigrateTransriptsCloningsData`*, and then add the desired changes in the `up` block, then execute `db:migrate` to update the required changes.

My choice would be To add a new rake task and executing it. like `bundle exec rake migrate_transcripts_data:start` instead of keeping that logic in the db/migrate/your_new_migration_file, choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

`reset_column_information` should be the correct way to resolve this sort of problem if you want to use models in a migration. This isn't without its problems though.

I suspect the issue is that you are calling it too late somehow. Put it first thing in the up method of the second migration or after the `add_column` in the first migration.

Answer (score 0):

I may assume that the issue is in Apartment.tenant_names.
In the second migration, you are switching tenants by `Apartment::Tenant.switch(firm.tenant)`, but I do not see similar in the first migrations. Probably tenant names are in DB, not in configs.
I am pretty sure that you may find samples of the appropriate `add_column` in your previous migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use structure migrations to modify data.

Use rake tasks, or [data-migrate](https://github.com/ilyakatz/data-migrate) gem instead.

Also, do not use automatic data migrations, if you not ensure, that it working as expected on production server.
Always store data before modifications and write modification rollback code.